# internal card reader is not working

Tags: 14.04, sd-card, card-reader

I have Dell vostro 3560 running on ubuntu 14.04, and it's card reader is not working.
Result of lsusb is

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:648b Microdia Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a very nice answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102348).

To summarize:

`$ sudo modprobe rts5139` to load the kernel module

On my system, this was sufficient to mount the SD card.

To make the change permanent, you can modify the configuration files as shown in the link.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04 the 3.18+ kernel introduced a new driver called rtsx, which replaced rts5139. To date this newer driver continues to cause issues with the RTS5129. I know it's not a perfect solution, but I have a temporary workaround: https://github.com/asymingt/rts5139